# Update a widget from a service

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to update a widget from a service... the service start a thread that execute this code

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(Worker.this);
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(Worker.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.mywidget);
ComponentName projectWidget = new ComponentName(Worker.this, MyWidget.class);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetstate, "update");
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(projectWidget, remoteViews);
```

the onUpdate method just print a log, but this log is printed only when I create the widget, not everytime the thread cycles... where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not wrong. You just update the widget without calling `onUpdate()`. It's just a convinience method that gets called in response to the `ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast by the system. You don't *have* to call it to update a widget, it also just works like you did here. ¹

To invoke it you can send the broadcast or call it by hand though, it's a good idea to keep the widget update functionality in one place from a code structure point of view to find things easily.

*¹ Take a look at the [`AppWidgetProvider` source, line 56](http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java&q=AppWidgetProvider%20package%3aandroid&type=cs&l=56). The whole `AppWidgetProvider` is just a `BroadcastReceiver` that does some work for you already - and it does start the update in the same way.*

Comment: uhm you're right, but why the log is not printed? ^^ tried to change the text anyway and this works.. thanks ^^

Comment: As said, the widget gets updated. But not from `onUpdate()`. If you put a log call between the codelines in the service which you posted above, you should see that called instead.